# load a typescript file in another typescript file by using reference

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm new to Typescript. I'd like to load a Typescript file in another Typescript file by using the `<reference>` tag.

I did something but it doesn't work! Please help me.

**first.ts:**

```
import * as $ from './JQuery';

alert("Message 2: I want to run!");
$("#myParagraph").click(function () {
    alert("hello!");
});
```

**app.ts:**

```
/// <reference path="./first.ts"/>

alert("Message 1: app.ts loaded!");
```

**output app.ts is app.js (automatic generated)**

```
/// <reference path="./first.ts"/>
alert("Message 1: app.ts loaded!");
```

As you see that, contains of first.ts did not load in app.js file.
How can I solve this problem?
[image: first.ts not found!]

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/scripts",
    "module": "umd"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `--outFile` parameter to the TypeScript compiler to concatenate everything into one file. The browser won't parse the `<reference>` tag.

Like this:

`tsc --outFile my-big-javascript.js`